# Программа должны вывести несколько разных прямоугольника в 2х разных местах , но , когда доходит до if , то прекращает свою работу.Как исправить?

Tags: javascript

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var colors = ["aqua", "blue", "fuchsia", "green", "cyan", "lime", "maroon",
  "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow", "azure",
  "gold", "bisque", "pink", "orange"
];
var numColors = colors.length;
var maxL = 38;
var minL = 10;
var maxH = 170;
var minH = 100;
var maxW = 8;
var minW = 0;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function drowRect(ox, oy, long, hi, collo) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.shadowColor = "gray";
  context.shadowOffsetX = 1;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 1;
  context.shadowBlur = 5;
  context.fillStyle = collo;
  context.fillRect(ox, oy, long, hi);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

function chernoeOblacko() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "slategrey";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

function Derevia() {
  var jesica = getRandomInt(1, 3);
  chernoeOblacko();
  Derevo(440, 300, 1);
}

function Derevo(smeshX, smeshY, chislo) {
  var numRect = getRandomInt(2, 10);

  for (var n = 0; n < numRect; n++) {
    var xPo = getRandomInt(240 + smeshX, 280 + smeshX);
    var yPo = getRandomInt(120 + smeshY, 150 + smeshY);
    var colorFand = Math.random() * (numColors - 1);
    colorFand = Math.round(colorFand);
    var cooolor = colors[colorFand];
    var rehi = getRandomInt(50, 100);
    var relon = getRandomInt(4, 8);
    drowRect(xPo, yPo, relon, rehi, cooolor);
    if (jesica == chislo) {
      drowRect(xPo - smeshX, yPo - smeshY, relon, rehi, cooolor);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="750"></canvas><br>
<input type="button" onclick="Derevia()" value="Нажми сюда и вырастет волщебное дерево! ">
```

Comment: Откуда следует, что прекращает работу?

Comment: @Эникейщик, отсюда: _Uncaught ReferenceError: jesica is not defined_

Comment: 1. Почему этого текста нет в вопросе? 2. Что непонятно в этом тексте? Текст ошибки предельно ясен. Вперёд, исправлять!

Comment: @Эникейщик Так автор как раз и спрашивает, как исправить. И вроде нигде не говорит, что само сообщение об ошибке ему непонятно.

Comment: @Yaant Ну вы же не первый день тут, знаете правила оформления вопросов. Я уж не говорю про то, что вопрошающего ожидаются собственные усилия по решению проблемы, чего в этом случае нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну, что сам по себе вопрос требует доработки, это очевидно, но автор-то тут как раз первый день, так что это, пожалуй, простительно.  :) И все же реплика "вперед, исправлять!" в ответ на прямой вопрос "как исправить?" выглядит слегка странно. :)

Comment: @Yaant С репликой погорячился, согласен, убрать уже не могу. А этот прямой вопрос так далеко запрятан в заголовке, что я его и не заметил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное , извините, буквально только сегодня зарегистрировался,потому и не знал , как оформлять вопрос.Буду знать теперь <3

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что `jesica` определена в другой области видимости. Поэтому можно просто передать её как параметр в функцию `Derevo()`:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var colors = ["aqua", "blue", "fuchsia", "green", "cyan", "lime", "maroon",
  "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow", "azure",
  "gold", "bisque", "pink", "orange"
];
var numColors = colors.length;
var maxL = 38;
var minL = 10;
var maxH = 170;
var minH = 100;
var maxW = 8;
var minW = 0;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function drowRect(ox, oy, long, hi, collo) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.shadowColor = "gray";
  context.shadowOffsetX = 1;
  context.shadowOffsetY = 1;
  context.shadowBlur = 5;
  context.fillStyle = collo;
  context.fillRect(ox, oy, long, hi);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

function chernoeOblacko() {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = "slategrey";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 750);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

function Derevia() {
  var jesica = getRandomInt(1, 3);
  chernoeOblacko();
  Derevo(440, 300, 1, jesica);
}

function Derevo(smeshX, smeshY, chislo, jesica) {
  var numRect = getRandomInt(2, 10);

  for (var n = 0; n < numRect; n++) {
    var xPo = getRandomInt(240 + smeshX, 280 + smeshX);
    var yPo = getRandomInt(120 + smeshY, 150 + smeshY);
    var colorFand = Math.random() * (numColors - 1);
    colorFand = Math.round(colorFand);
    var cooolor = colors[colorFand];
    var rehi = getRandomInt(50, 100);
    var relon = getRandomInt(4, 8);
    drowRect(xPo, yPo, relon, rehi, cooolor);
    if (jesica == chislo) {
      drowRect(xPo - smeshX, yPo - smeshY, relon, rehi, cooolor);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="750"></canvas><br>
<input type="button" onclick="Derevia()" value="Нажми сюда и вырастет волщебное дерево! ">
```